# RBAC in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I have a **users** table in my sql server 2008 which has
 `username, password, email,first name, last name and user group`.

I want to display my website controls specific to that user groups once the user logs in.

Could you please help in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign user's `user group` is a session variable at the time of log in. Now you can set (may be on page_load) your pages's controls visibility upon that value.

Something like this,

```
If(Session["UserGroup"] == "1")
{
    ControlID.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    ControlID.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: how to get usergroup retrieved from database at the time of login?

Comment: when you are checking user credentials for login, if the credentials are fine then fetch that Usergroup from your `users` table.

Comment: @BAdminThanks got it.